# Address To Const Char *?

Tags: c++

If I have an address, like the one below:

```
.radat:010FBD40 ; char byte_10FBD40[]
```

How would I turn it into a `const char*` in my C++ program? The address will never change or move or anything.

Comment: You can always cast anything to const char*.

Comment: But what code do you use to change 0x1234 to a const char?

Comment: `const char* addr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(0x1234);`

Comment: Oh, thanks! It works

Comment: @DeiDei: Do not answer in the comments section please

Answer (score 1):

You may reinterpret an integer as a memory address, then use it to initialise a pointer:

```
const char* addr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(0x010FBD40);
```

It is, of course, your responsibility to promise that a `char` array (or compatible object) lives there.

Comment: This one works too! And i'm very sure the char is and will always be there.

Comment: It's the same "one". I posted it as an answer, which is where the information should be.